# Texto de Android Studio ilegible

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Tengo un problema en `Android Studio`, y es que sin importar qué archivo o proyecto abra (incluso proyectos nuevos), el contenido de cada texto en el editor es ilegible, incluso los números de línea.

Todo pasó luego de un push a un repositorio. Al cargar el proyecto en `Android Studio`, todo salió tal cual la imagen.

[image: Texto ilegible]

Tengo las siguientes consideraciones:

> - No importa el archivo que abra, todo se ve igual
> - Los archivos están bien al abrirlos con otro editor
> - El idioma de todo el IDE es el correcto. Solo el editor se corrompe
> - Al copiar un texto cualquiera del editor al portapapeles, el texto se pega bien en cualquier otro sitio, como si nada.

Comment: Hola. No puedo ayudarte con una idea de solución. Pero, en Software Recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com tratan de modo estecífico ese tipo de problemas y es posible que encuentres la orientación que necesitas.

Comment: Wow eso si que esta raro! Ya intentaste cambiar la codificación del texto? Esa opción aparece debajo a la izquierda: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiuSB.png Cámbialo a UTF-8 si esta diferente.

Comment: Sí. Todo está en UTF-8 y aparte, hasta los números de línea se corrompen.

Comment: me paso una vez, se soluciona cambiando la fuente desde las opciones

Comment: ¡Gracias @zhet! Funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes cambiar el tipo de fuente en **File > Settings > Editor > Font**

Comment: ¡Gracias hombre! Problema resuelto

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la información que proporcionas :

> Los archivos están bien al abrirlos con otro editor, El idioma de todo
>   el IDE es el correcto. Solo el editor se corrompe

**En realidad los archivos NO se corrompen, lo que sucede es que tienes configurado otro tipo de codificación el cual no permite visualizar los caracteres correctamente.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambia la configuración de tu IDE, comúnmente la codificación usada es `UTF-8`.

---

Por ejemplo, si tengo configurada por error la codificación `IBM-Thai`, visualizo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si cambio a `UTF-8` se muestra correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]